# Parse tag content of simple HTML form/table using Regular Expression

Tags: html, regex

I have a simple HTML file only containing a table with no further CSS or any other attributes. The structure of this file never changes, but its content is always different.

I try to match the content of a specific cell (td) which shall give me the **name** of the **first occurence of a contact** which has the **type 'Misc'**.

In my example I try to match the name 'Michael Jackson':

[image: HTML table]

This is what I've got so far:

```
(<td>\s*Contact:\s*<\/td>((?!<br>).)*<td>\s*Misc\s*<\/td>)
```

But this only selects the two contact blocks containing the type 'Misc'.  I don't know how to go on from this point ...

Here again is my regex and the HTML string I am using:

- https://regex101.com/r/xIzr3a/1/

Thanks for any help or advises!

Comment: would you consider adding `class` or `id` in order to easily process your table with javascript? Or is it a requirement to do it via regex?

Comment: the structure of the HTML is given, there is no possibility to add classes or id's. And yea, regex is a requirement..